# Binding SelectedValue through converter not matching anything in ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I've got a ComboBox that looks like the following, where `SelectedValue` is bound to an `int` and `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of `string`s:

```
<ComboBox
  SelectedValue="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource PriorityInt2StringConverter}}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StringToIntDictionary.Keys, Source={x:Static helpers:HelperClass.Instance}}"/>
```

The `PriorityInt2StringConverter` converter looks like this:

```
public class PriorityIntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly HelperClass helper = HelperClass.Instance;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            int priority = (int)value;
            string priorityStr;
            if (helper.IntToStringDictionary.TryGetValue(priority, out priorityStr))
            {
                value = priorityStr;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string priority = value as string;
        if (priority != null)
        {
            int priorityInt;
            if (helper.StringToIntDictionary.TryGetValue(priority, out priorityInt))
            {
                value = priorityInt;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The combobox options are populating as I would expect, and when the converter is called, it returns as expected, but it is only called when the control is first rendered -- never on selection change when I would have expected.

**Now, the problem: When the ComboBox selection is changed, the change does not stick -- the setter on `Value` is never called and the selection is lost.**

Answer (score 0):

Your binding looks OK, so when the selection changes, the `ConvertBack` method of your converter should be called. Have you checked that?

It's important that the returned `value` of the `ConvertBack` method actually returns an integer. Otherwise the `Value` property which is binded cannot be set properly.

If your `if`-statement:

```
if (helper.StringToIntDictionary.TryGetValue(priority, out priorityInt))
```

returns `false`, the `value` never gets set to an integer and so the setter of the `Value` property never gets called. You will also get an error, which can be seen in the Output-Window when debugging (probably a `FormatException`).

So I would start investigating exactly at the `ConvertBack` method. Make sure that the conversion from `string` to `int` works in every case. Maybe you should also specify a default value, which will be returned if the `TryGetValue` method returns `false` to make sure that a valid value will be returned in every case.

Comment: The Convert/ConvertBack are not called past the control's initial startup though. I've got breakpoints at the top of both and I hit Convert 2 times during startup and ConvertBack 1 time during startup, but neither after then. I presume matching against the ItemsSource cannot possibly work if each change in selection doesn't fire Convert/ConvertBack..?

Comment: Your presumption is correct. The problem occurs earlier. Seems like the binding gets broken after initial loading of the control. Do you have other bindings in the control and do those bindings work after initial loading? Is the `DataContext` set correctly after the initial load?